# How to insert link in Bibliography in latex

Tags: bibliographies

I am trying to write the following code in latex. But their output is not coming nicely. How to modify this code

```
\bibitem{wikibook}
        Repetition code, 
        \url{https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Repetition_code}


\bibitem{ccode}
        Cyclic Codes, 
\url{http://www.work.caltech.edu/~ling/webs/EE127/EE127A/handout/Ch8.pdf}


\bibitem{cth}
        \text{ Coding theory: the first 50 years}
        \url{https://plus.maths.org/content/coding-theory-first-50-years}
```

Comment: Please clarify what you mean by "output is not coming nicely". E.g., are you getting overfull or underfull lines? Large gaps between words? Something else? Please be specific.

Comment: there are large gaps in the words

Answer (score 2):

I will assume that you're loading the `url` and/or the `hyperref` package. To avoid getting large gaps between words, I suggest you load the `xurl` package instead of the `url` package. If you load the `hyperref` package as well, be sure load it *after`the`xurl` package.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xurl} % not 'url'
\usepackage[colorlinks,allcolors=blue]{hyperref} % optional

\begin{document}
\begin{thebibliography}{9}
\bibitem{wikibook}
   Repetition code, 
   \url{https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Repetition_code}

\bibitem{ccode}
   Cyclic Codes, 
   \url{http://www.work.caltech.edu/~ling/webs/EE127/EE127A/handout/Ch8.pdf}

\bibitem{cth}
   Coding theory: the first 50 years,
   \url{https://plus.maths.org/content/coding-theory-first-50-years}
\end{thebibliography}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I am getting an error message xurl.sty not found

Comment: @JSN - The `xurl` package was released in December 2017. When did you most recently update your TeX distribution?

Comment: Ok. I am writting in Overleaf online.

Comment: @JSN - it would have been really useful to mention up front the fact that you use Overleaf. I don't use Overleaf myself, but I understand it still uses TeXLive2016 as its TeX distribution. I think I also read recently -- can't remember where, though -- that Overleaf is about to update to TeXLive2018 "soon",